# How can I change label's content from a button being clicked in another window?

Tags: c#

This is the first ever thing I've ever done that's to do with C# but I have learnt lua and python in the past. I wanted to make a bingo app for when some friends come around and I thought I'd give it a go. Basically I have 2 windows, 1 for the bingo caller and one that I can display on the screen for the players to see. The bingo caller window has all the controls but I want to be able to change things on the players window. I have a button and when I click it I want it to make an image visible and change some text saying 'We have a winner'. However I **cannot** find a way to change the things in a different window :(

Here is my code aswell as some pictures.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Window window = new Window1();
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            window.Show();
            PlayBingo.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            DeclareWinner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            RollNumber.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Declare_Winner(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Roll_Number(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

[Image of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqNCS.png)

**EDIT**

```
        public string BingoNumberChange(string bingonumber)
        {
            BingoNo.Content = bingonumber;
            return bingonumber;
        }
```

I created this function in my window1 script. However I cannot call it from the MainWindow Script???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a public method in the Window1 class which accept new text and call this method from main window. You can do this for multiple window class with Interface

```
public class Window1 : Window
{
   // skip all other code
   public void SetLabelText(string str)
   {
       label1.Content= str;
   }
}
```

Call this method from MainWindow button click

```
Window1 newWindowobj = new Window1():
newWindowobj.SetLabel("new text");
newWindowobj.Show();
```

Another Approach

IContentUpdatable.cs

```
public interface IContentUpdatable
{
    void UpdateContent(string content);
}
```

Window1 Code

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, IContentUpdatable
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UpdateContent(string content)
    {
        lblCaption.Content = content;
    }
}
```

MainWindow Code

```
 Window1 window1 = new Window1();
 private void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     ((IContentUpdatable)window1).UpdateContent("Passed from Main Window");
     window1.Show();
 }
```

Comment: How do you create a function?

Comment: I have posted my function above. Can you see why it is not working?

Comment: You are not called "BingoNumberChange" from Mainwindow Button click event.